# Select #id.html in data response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
function getJobs2(pars) {
    $.ajax({
        //alert(pars);
        url: 'lib/ajax/getJobs2.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: pars,
        success: function (data) {
            /* THIS line returns allways null*/
            console.log($(data).find('#home_right').html());
            /* I can see #home_right in the output!! */
            console.log(data);
            $('#home_right').html($(data).find('#home_right').html());
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that:

`$(data).find('#myDiv').html()` is not returning the HTML I need... but null. And i can ee the desired div in the whole data output..

Am i selecting it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `#home_right` is a top level element in the response. Use [`.filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) then:

```
$('#home_right').html($(data).filter('#home_right').html());
```

`.find` only searchers for **descendants** of the selected elements, not for selected elements themselves.

If you'd post the response, it would be easier to provide a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
console.log($("<div class='dummy-wrapper'>" + data + "</div>").find("#home_right"));
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ARpPs/)